# SQL filtering for table based on 3rd column's value

Tags: sql, filtering

[image]

How should my SQL be so that the table mentioned above should have the expected output using SQL. The filtering happens using the col 3 value. Row with the highest col 3 value for a particular col 1 value is selected in the output.

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using?

Comment: ANSI SQL in Snowflake

Comment: Please do *not* post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 from (
    SELECT row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col3 desc) sn, * from your_table_name
) a WHERE sn=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you require the usage of the `WHERE` clause in SQL which acts as a method to filter results based on a conditional.

Considering you want all entries rather than any given entry one that matches, you can use the following (written in MySQL) which uses a nested `SELECT` statement:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE col3=(SELECT MAX(col3) FROM Table);
```